# Why is a "Czech bed roll" called this? History, uses?

Tags: gear, camping, wild-camping

This was actually something new I came across recently. A [Czech bed roll](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cXCr7TVaP24).

I've never seen a set up like this before. I was also intrigued by the name.

Has anyone used one of these? Advantages/disadvantages?

Why are they called Czech bed rolls? Especially the Czech bit?

### Edit

Yes, I know the example I tagged was Czech army surplus. I am more interested in the history/usage of these things. The post I came across this on refereed to this as a more generic title.

Comment: They do look interesting! Never heard of them myself either.

Comment: Interesting indeed. I have the [USA one](http://www.ebay.com/bhp/us-military-sleeping-bag). Very warm, extremely heavy.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's because it's Czech Army surplus, so something that is/was used in the Czech army.

Comment: It's 'Czech army bed roll'. So 2 first adjectives specify only the origin. To make the question broader, and not based on simple misunderstanding, you can reedit to ask if it's worth buying surplus army sleeping bags or bed rolls. Old military stuff tends to be quite heavy.

Comment: That's just stating the obvious. I've clarified my question

Comment: Bedrolls have been around since the times of the Roman empire, it's literally a bed that you can roll up. Would you like me to explain why  soldiers might want to roll up their bed?  There's your history. In modern times it is synonymous with a sleeping bag, athough they don't necessarily close and many sleeping bags can be stuffed in a sac. There's nothing unique about Czech bedrolls besides that they've been commissioned for the Czech army.

Comment: Your question has the answer. And @furtive's answer clarifies. The ones you are looking at are called this because they are from the Czech Army. Ones from other countries armies are **not** called Czech beds!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is actually a misconception of the naming convention.

Comment: These things exist all over the world. In Australia, they're called "swag".

Comment: The link now points to a pair of trousers. You might want to fix it to show a correct example, since I doubt that these trousers are a good replacement for a sleeping bag ;-)

Comment: Thanks @anderas updated to a youtube video now, should remain more consistent

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am Czech! The blanket rolls were used as standard issue bedrolls in the Army. In barracks, they were also used on the cots instead of the bed blankets and sheets issued, because as anyone knows who has been in the army, making your bed in the morning and then suffering barracks inspection with roll call is a real pain in the butt!

It saved us time and made inspection much easier, so we just unrolled them at night and slept in that. Also in the field, a thermal underlay was placed between the waterproof layer and the inner layer, and then sleeping under a overhead waterproof roof, like a poncho.

The system worked very well, heavy, but bulletproof for lumbering soldiers in the field.